# MONGODB-QUERY WITH DIFFERENT DOCUMENTS

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

[IMAGE OF MY DOCUMENT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JLkB.png)

This is one of my document with trip detailS.The return ride taking passenger will have his drop latlong of one document equal to pickup lat long of another document.But I am not able to query with taking one field and query with all other documents matching the condition.

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("5a1058cd2514972098b5b4e6"),

"trip_id" : 895728,

"pass_id" : 1,

"driver_id" : 5119,

"pick_lat" : 16.863973,

"pick_lon" : 96.11646259999999,

"drop_lat" : 16.806106699999997,

"drop_lon" : 96.15429830000001,

"pickup_date" : ISODate("2017-10-27T13:00:58.000+05:30"),

"drop_date" : ISODate("2017-10-27T14:10:21.000+05:30"),

"distance" : 11.13,

"coordinates" : [
        96.11646259999999,
        16.863973
    ],
    "type" : "Point",
    "
loglat" : {

"type" : "Point",

"coordinates" : [
            96.11646259999999,
            16.863973

]
    }
},
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried aggregate operators in pymongo